# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (>)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My project is being developed in Mvc3.
This questions is asked on numerous occassions and many blogs are also there for this issue. But I couldnt find satisfying solution and still giving me error "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (>)." on my hosted solution.

My web.config file

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

I have also stated ValidateInput[(False)] to corrosponding action

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Category(int storeid, string storename,int categoryId)
        {
        }
```

Comment: For what particular request exactly? Is it a malicious request or a geniune one?

Comment: I think the request is malicious. request correct is mysite.com/s/1/c/cname i think somebody has mistakenly or knowingly added some special characters to end of url.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Have you checked the event log? It should provide you with a lot more information.

Comment: Yes its logged in my error table

Answer (score 2):

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (>)

error you are getting because of security issues just write this in config file:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `requestPathInvalidCharacters=""` from the following

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Either way, you may want to look at Encoding the URL, `>` would be `%3C`, this would prevent any security risks.